# jQuery Plugin Boxy, before boxy loading

Tags: jquery, boxy

In vBulletin version 4.1.4, to open a window with attachments, I use the jQuery Plugin, [Boxy](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/boxy/) .  It is in the template, `threadbit` and is working fine. But when the box is loading, I want to show an image that something is happening.  After the loading process, this image should be removed.  For this process I modified the template code.

This works:

```
<code class="html">
    <div class="myThemaRating" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <span onclick='new Boxy.load( "{vb:raw vboptions.bburl}/misc.php?{vb:raw session.sessionurl}do=showattachments&amp;t={vb:raw thread.threadid}", {title:"Anhang-Dateien im Forum:", closeText:"schliessen", cache:true} )'>
            <i m g s_c="{vb:stylevar i m g dir_icons}/Icon_6 . png" border="0" alt="{vb:rawphrase x_attachments, {vb:raw thread.attach}}" />&nbsp;
        </span>
    </div>
</code>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<code>    
    <div class="myThemaRating" style="cursor:pointer;">
        <span onclick='new Boxy.load( "{vb:raw vboptions.bburl}/misc.php?{vb:raw session.sessionurl}do=showattachments&amp;t={vb:raw thread.threadid}", {title:"Anhang-Dateien im Forum:", closeText:"schliessen", cache:true }, behaviours:function(r) { $(r).click( $("# myImagesLoad _{vb:raw thread.threadid}").attr({ src: "{vb:stylevar i m g dir_icons}/ajax-loader . gif", alt: "Fenster wird geladen" }) ); } }  ' >
            <i m g s_c="{vb:stylevar imgdir_icons}/1pixel . png" id="myImagesLoad_{vb:raw thread.threadid}" width="10" border="1"> <!-- load image -->
            <i m g s_c="{vb:stylevar imgdir_icons}/Icon_6 . png" border="0" alt="{vb:rawphrase x_attachments, {vb:raw thread.attach}}" />&nbsp;
        </span>
    </div>
</code>
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can fix this?

Comment: please re-format your question...

Comment: i edited the question, but it needs to be approved, i don't have the rights yet :) the only thing i left in were the `<code></code>` tags, though i believe those are some vbulletin markup but left them in because i wasn't sure

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for help and sorry my english :-(